# Нужна помощь с selenium 3

Tags: python, selenium

Сайт для теста : https://tgstat.ru/channel/@FilmCCCP

Необходимо спарсить текст, который я выделил красным:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь это сделать вот таким кодом и не получается:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time


url = 'https://tgstat.ru/channel/@FilmCCCP'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\TGstat\chrome\chromedriver.exe')

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(3)
    channel_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//p[@class='card-text mt-3']").get_attribute('title')
    print(channel_info)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Так же, пробовал так:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time


url = 'https://tgstat.ru/channel/@FilmCCCP'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\TGstat\chrome\chromedriver.exe')

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(3)
    channel_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//p[@class='card-text mt-3']").text
    print(channel_info)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достал текст через родительский к `p` тег `<div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-6">`. Так как там еще есть текст, то взял только нужный.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = 'https://tgstat.ru/channel/@FilmCCCP'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.col-12.col-sm-7.col-md-8.col-lg-6")))

    print(*element.text.split("\n")[-2:])
    
finally:
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.quit()

----------------------------------

#Советские фильмы #КиноСССР #Мосфильм #Ленфильм #Кино #Смотретьонлайн
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает